# Blender shape keys aren't animating properly

Tags: animation, keyframes, shape-keys, timeline

I am trying to animate a hinged lid so that the hinge will not poke through the bottom, and that it will also properly show itself. I followed many tutorials word-for-word, but when I do what they do, the animation doesn't play properly. I added a keyframe to the hinge called "Stretched", and then edited it by stretching part of it. It checks out, because when I click the pin after clicking "stretched", the object morphs instantly to the stretched shape key. However, when I set the slider to 0 and create a keyframe at frame 0, then set the slider to 1 and create a keyframe at frame 70 (end of animation), nothing happens. The hinge doesn't stretch. I've made sure to turn off all pins and such, but nothing helps. Here are pics: [image: stretched is on using pin]
[image: what it looks like when stretched is 0]

File: [image]

Comment: This might be a case where you have to post the .blend file to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ so we can experiment with it to figure out what is going on.

Comment: Done. I uploaded the .blend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your screenshot you can see that your "stretched" shape key was relative to the "stretched" shape key instead of the Basis shape key.  Since it was relative to itself, it represented no deltas.  If you change "stretched"'s Blend: relative_key from "stretched" to "Basis", then the shape key works.

Comment: Ohhhh. I did eventually delete the shape key and try again a while ago, and it worked. I'll bet it worked because it reset the relation object to basis. I must have changed the relation object without noticing it or while becoming frustrated. Thanks for helping show me what the problem was.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it. It turns out that all I needed to do was delete the shape keys and try again. I can't believe the fix was so simple.

Comment: Well, that's a brutal solution.  I'm still a little curious how the internal data became corrupted.  I hope to get around to exploring it using python.

Comment: Turns out it was my fault. As user Mutant Bob pointed out, I had set the "stretched" shape key relative to "stretched" instead of the basis shape key by accident.